# Issues during 'make pycaffe' on OSX

Tags: python, macos, caffe, pycaffe

I am getting the below error while trying to run `make pycaffe` on after installing caffe on mac.

```
CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:10:10: fatal error: 'numpy/arrayobject.h' file not found
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
         ^ 1 error generated. make: *** [python/caffe/_caffe.so] Error 1
```

Below is the part of my Makefile.config for reference:
    # We need to be able to find Python.h and numpy/arrayobject.h.

PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python2.7 \
                    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include

Though I am not able to find /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ on my machine, please give suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue while compiling for pycaffe

```
CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:10:10:
```

fatal error:

> numpy/arrayobject.h file not found

This indicates that numpy is not installed, I used the following command to fix my issue.

```
$ conda install -c anaconda numpy=1.12.1
```